# Capture JavaScript variable in another page?

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new window when the user fills an input, then he'll choose something from the opened window(the selected values will be in the form of an array) and then when he's done to close the new window, get the values array back in the first page and fill the next section of the form with those values.

This is something like Twitter's authorize page, the question is how can I pass the variable back to the initial page?

Many thanks

UPDATE:
I found this to change the value of a form input in the window that opened it. I don't want to redirect or anything, just to capture a value and then close the pop-up.

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('searchText').value='something';
```

Comment: Andrew, take a look at my edited answer. Perhaps it's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `window.opener` object

Example, you can set the location (redirect) the parent window from the pop up window

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function redirect(){
    window.opener.document.location = 'Newurl.html';
  }
</script>

<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:redirect()'>Redirect the window opener</a>
```

To set a value of a field inside a form you can do something like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function changeVal(newVal){
    window.opener.document.getElementById('field_id').value = newVal;
  }
</script>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:changeVal("new value")'>Change the field value</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the serialized array in cookies (I don't know Twitter).